# SignalR connection threading with Android

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, signalr

this has been confusing me for a while and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Xamarin.Android with a SignalR client in a portable class library to create a messaging app.

Essentially, I have two classes in my Android layer: a fragment for the UI and a class that controls the SignalR connection (SignalRContoller, a singleton) which starts/stops a signalR connection and passes messages to and from the UI. Here is how the connection is handled in the fragment as of now:

```cs
public override async void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    //Do some startup stuff

    if (!SignalRController.IsRunning)
    {
        try
        {
            await SignalRController.Instance.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "error", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }

   SignalRController.Instance.ConnectionStateChanged += onConnectionStateChange;
}
```

This works fine and doesn't throw any exceptions. However, this awaits until after the signalR connection has started before hooking up my event handler which means I can't show any updates to let the user know that the connection is connecting, or reconnecting etc.

So I hooked up the event handler before calling start:

```
...
SignalRController.Instance.ConnectionStateChanged += onConnectionStateChange;
await SignalRController.Instance.Start();
...
```

By swapping the order of these statements I get a `JavaRuntimeException` when trying to call connection.start() from signalR with the message:
`"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"`

This is how the singleton instance is being returned from the SignalRController:

```
public static SignalRController Instance
{
    get
    {
        lock (instanceLock)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new SignalRController();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Since this is similar to an error trying to update the UI from a non-UI thread I have tried several methods as described by JP on the xamarin forums [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2400/android-ui-threading) but with no luck. Can someone explain why the swapping of these statements would cause this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So I have figured this out. Hopefully this can help anyone else with a similar problem.

By hooking up the event handlers first I'm guessing there was some weird context switching going on.

What I have done is set up the singleton instance with an initial call: `SignalRController.Instance.Setup(Activity activity)` and passed in a reference to the calling activity before calling `await Instance.Start()` or hooking up any event handlers. Then I wrap all events raised by the singleton with `activity.RunOnUiThread(()=>onConnectionStateChanged);`.

Thanks to anyone that took the time to read this.